# Finite Second Moment Sufficient Condition

Tags: probability-theory

> For real random variable $X$, define $A(X):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{Pr(|X|>t)}dt$. Prove $A(X)<\infty$ implies that $EX^2<\infty$ and that $E|X|^{2+\delta}<\infty$ for some $\delta>0$ implies that $A(X)<\infty$.

---

This statement appears on Mathematical Foundation of Infinite Dimensional Statistical Model by Gine and Nickl, page 132. I tried to apply the tail probability integration formula for the second moment but still cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Because $t \mapsto \mathbb{P}(|X|>t)$ is decreasing, for all $t$, we have :
$$A(X)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{ \mathbb{P}( |X|>s)}ds \ge t\sqrt{ \mathbb{P}( |X|>t)}$$
Thus
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)= \int_{0}^{\infty} 2s\mathbb{P}( |X|>s)ds \le 2A(X) \int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{ \mathbb{P}( |X|>s)}ds = 2A(X)^2$$
Thus if $A(x)<\infty$, $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ must be finite

---

If $\mathbb{E}(|X|^{2+\delta})$ is finite, then
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{1+\delta}\mathbb{P}(|X|>t)dt$$
is also finite. Besides,
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{1+\delta}}dt<\infty$$
So by Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, we imply:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\mathbb{P}(|X|>t)}dt$$
is finite.
Hence $A(X)$ is finite.